# How to Crawl a PHP generated image

Tags: php, image, http-headers, php-gd, google-crawlers

I have a website textscloud.com
 In this website i make the image with the PHP GD library. Here is a link to a demo:

In this page i allow the user to download the image on which text will pe printed. download link is like

This download.php file has a header for making the image with PHP GD Library and download the file like this

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
```

But google didn't crawl these images. Does anyone know the solution? I can't store these image in server.

Comment: It's probably the `Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename` that causes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention *how* you are feeding the beast, so I suggest you start by providing google a site map via their [webmaster toolkit](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools). You can specifically list the images that you want crawled. Google provides good [help articles](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636) to get you going.

Comment: i submitted the all links of images in webmaster toolkit. and nothing happend, and their help articles are suck.

Comment: @Rishi I've found it takes a while (a week or so) to get images indexed. If you want to edit your question (or create a new one) and include a sample of the sitemap XML, someone can double-check that.

Comment: the problem is... what will google index if you just link to the picture? It can't guess the contents (at least I think so as of now) and there is no decription provided (no html which describes an image embedded in the same page).

Answer (score 0):

Google can't index images that are not stored permanently, I'm quite sure it can't even index images without context (i.e. which are not part of a describing/linking page).

Comment: sorry but i saw many website in which google crawl these type of images like findicons.com, may be i am right or not. but thanx for your answer

Comment: there, every mage is accompanied by a html page describing it. that's different.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to:

Send a cache header to allow caching of the image.

Rewrite the actual url to someting like: http://textscloud.com/get_img/download/VkZaU1FtUXdNVVZWVkZKT1ZWUXdPUT09.png (should match your filename header)

Comment: how i do this cache header, can you tell me a little more about it, and thanx for your help